# Why doesn't my Databricks Spark job finish even after all tasks have finished?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I'm seeing some of my jobs stuck waiting in "Running command..." stage even after all tasks have finished and there are "0" running.

- What might be causing this?
- Which logs should I be looking at to resolve this?

Thanks

Screenshot:

[image: Spark job progress screenshot with all tasks completed but job still running]

Comment: It means that although distributed processing has completed, SparkContext created in Spark driver program is still active. You may be able to find out what driver is doing from the driver's stderr log.

Comment: @mazaneicha Interestingly, I saw a lot of "Delete" related logs. I'm assuming this is because I'm overwriting over already written output. It seems to be faster when I deleted the older files before writing new ones.

Comment: Depending on the FileOutputCommitter algorithm version, driver might be required to commit all the work executed in distributed phase, including moving all files from temp/staging directories to their final place).

Comment: @mazaneicha Is there a way to configure it such that overwriting existing output wouldn't have such high overhead (from deletes)?

I want to avoid manually deleting the old files before overwriting. Also, between the time I deleted the old files and finish overwriting, the old files are unavailable for other scripts which may be trying to read it.